# Problems with lexical comparision

Tags: groovy, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I want to transform some XML using XSL and groovy. Im using javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory for it.

But comparision in my XLS file doesn't work like I imagine.

It can not tell me that 2.0.1 is greater then 2.0. Why? I think it should because of xsl:stylesheet version="2.0". Im doing something wrong?

Here are my files:

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<apis>
    <api version="2.0.1">
        <resource>
            <description>doc for API 2.0.1</description>
        </resource>
    </api>
</apis>
```

XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="api-version" select="2.0"/>
<xsl:template match="/apis/api[@version &gt; $api-version]/resource">
    <resource>
        <xsl:value-of select="description"></xsl:value-of>
    </resource>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And groovy script

```
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource

def workspacePath
def xslPath
def xslFileName
def xmlPath
def xmlFileName
def outputPath
def outputFileName
def xslt
def transformer
def xml
def output
def apiVersions

workspacePath = "C:/test/"
xslPath = "transformations/"
xslFileName = "test5.xsl"
xmlPath = "pendingFeature/"
xmlFileName = "test5.xml"
outputPath = "outputs/"

xslt = new File(workspacePath + xslPath + xslFileName).getText()
transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xslt)))
xml = new File(workspacePath + xmlPath + xmlFileName).getText()
outputFileName = "doc.html"
output = new FileOutputStream(workspacePath + outputPath + outputFileName)
transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml)), new StreamResult(output))
output.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to put an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 on the class path to have XSLT 2.0 support. And if you want to compare strings and not numbers then do

```
<xsl:param name="api-version" select="'2.0'"/>
<xsl:template match="/apis/api[@version &gt; $api-version]/resource">
```